# ANOVA (Type?) or Between Samples Test

Tags: anova, t-test, k-means

Let's say I want to measure blood oxygen levels using three devices. Devices 1 and 2 are new devices and Device 3 is a gold standard that provides accurate readings. I'm interested not in diagnostic accuracy, but the differences in the means between the three devices. I will apply all three devices to the same patient at the same time and record values. Each patient will be measured only once. I'm interested in the differences between Device 1 vs 2, 2 vs 3, and 1 vs 3.

I violate the assumptions of independence of samples by using the same patients between device groups, so I assume I cannot use One-Way ANOVA. I risk error rate problems if I use multiple between samples t-tests. I cannot use repeated measures ANOVA, as only one measure is being taken. What is the best solution for testing means?

Comment: You can use repeated measures ANOVA--you are making three measurements on each subject. Essentially this is just an extention of a paired t-test to three means instead of two. I think you might be thinking that repeated measurements must be at different time points.  That is not necessary. You could have the same measure at three time points or in your case different tools for measuring the same thing at one time point.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I was doing a sample size calculation in G*Power and misunderstood the difference between No. of Groups and No. of Measurements. I have three groups and one measurement taken per group, but I just needed to reverse the input. Most examples of RM ANOVA online seem to involve multiple measures too. Thank you for your help.